# React/Redux - memory footprint not proportionate to state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So my whole Redux state is perhaps around 3-4mb, but Chrome is reporting my tab's memory usage at around 400-500mb, which climbs the longer you use it.

I understand there are other things it needs the memory for (so I shouldn't expect a 1:1 relationship), but does anyone know how I'd attempt to reduce memory consumption?

On a fresh session (or Incognito tab), my app is running very smoothly. If it's open for an afternoon or so, performance suffers greatly.

- My Redux store isn't overly large,
- Same page/DOM nodes etc between the 2 normal and Incognito tabs
- Everything else is seemingly identical

I get that this is fairly vague, but I'm not sure what else to include. Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the [Google Chrome Performance Analysis Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools) to analyse the performance of your app and see where savings can be made.

That said, Google Chrome can be a memory-hungry application in general. You should try to consider whether this is a problem. If the Chrome session does not consume an amount of RAM which is hurting the overall computer's performance, then it is not a problem. Try running the application on a computer with very little RAM, as long as it stops consuming memory before it impacts performance, then it is a non-issue.

If it does not do this and it begins to consume more and more memory, you likely have a memory leak and should look to resolve this with the tools linked above.